# How to write value to html field from asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I have made an application in javascript using HTML fields in asp.net, as asp text boxes were disturbing the ids, so i used html fields, which are working fine with javascript, now i want to fetch database table columns on page load, and want to assign to html fields, what is the best way to do so? Help me!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go back to using the ASP TextBoxes and access the ids in JavaScript as follows:

```
<%= IDofTextBox.ClientID %>
```

It's probably the easiest as naturally they can then be accessed in the code behind very easily.

Comment: runat server changes the id, can i write sql code in asp, by including System.Data.SqlClient, is there any help for that, how to do it.

Comment: why are u wanting to use code in .aspx page? you can do with codebehind also

Comment: I cannot access HTML textfield from code behind, i can just read it, not write it. And i cannot use Textbox, cannot change to textboxes or anything else.

Comment: you can create globle public string variables in codebehind  and assign value to them and attach with server tag like e.g. <input type="text" value='<%= Studentname%>'>

Comment: Thanks , i have made class level variables, and my work got done :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use asp text boxes fine if you grab a reference in your javascript to their asp.net generated ID via <%= textboxname.ClientId %>

Comment: How can i include System.Data.SqlClient in asp page, and write database code in asp page, i have made a very big application, cant do what you suggest, but get me rid of this issue now please.

Comment: you can reference this sql class library if you need it just use "add reference" to your web project and then add it to your code behind in a using clause - you can put database code in code behind if you really want to - i wouldnt recommend it but its your call.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to do it (I wouldn't recommending it), but if its what you need, then it will work.

Add `method="post" action="<your path here>"` to your form element and when the submit button posts, you will be able to access all the form variables like so:

```
string txtName = Request["TextBox1"] ?? string.Empty; //replace textbox 1 with text box name
```

Just be sure to replace the action in form to your page etc..

But really, going back to `<asp:TextBox...` will save you a lot more time and as Ian suggested, you can access them with javascript by the server tags `<%= TextBox1.ClientId %>`

ps: also, the `??` is a null coalesce character. its a short form of saying

```
if(Request["textbox1"] != null)
    txtName = Request["textbox1"];
else
    txtName = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. You just need to add runat="server" and id="someName" to the html fields and access them in the code behind by its given id.